# Problem in converting timestamp string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

I have a dataset with timestamps in the format:

```
`'4/17/2020 5:55:00 AM'`
```

Please note there are **2 spaces between YYYY and HH** fields. The original time is in **'US/Eastern'** timezone. I am trying to convert it to **IST (Indian Standard Time)**. This should be 'Asia/Kolkata' from **pytz**

The code below is not working, and I have tried multiple versions of it. Even conversion to **UTC** is failing. The code block is:

```
`
est_ts = '4/17/2020 5:55:00 AM'
est = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
ist = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
print(dt.datetime.strptime(est_ts, '%m/%d/%Y  %I:%M:%S %p').astimezone(ist).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
`
```

This gives an output of:

```
`2020-04-17 07:25:00`
```

While the correct output should be:

```
`2020-04-17 15:25:00`
```

What is wrong with this code? Much appreciated.

Comment: the `localize()` method is the way to go, see drec4s answer below. See [here](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) on why you should also `normalize()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to `localize` the original timestamp, so that you can `normalize` to the desired location:

```
import datetime as dt
import pytz

est_ts = '4/17/2020 5:55:00 AM'
est = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
ist = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')

est_dt = est.localize(dt.datetime.strptime(est_ts, '%m/%d/%Y  %I:%M:%S %p'))
ist_dt = ist.normalize(est_dt.astimezone(ist))

print(ist_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
#2020-04-17 15:25:00
```